# Concept and templates no longer run with g++-11

Tags: c++, g++, c++20, c++-concepts

The following code :

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <concepts>
template<typename T,  typename KEY, typename JSON_VALUE, typename...KEYS>
concept json_concept = requires(T t, int index, std::string& json_body, KEY key, JSON_VALUE value, KEYS... keys)
{ 
    { t.template get_value<T>(keys...) } -> std::same_as<T>;
    { t.template get_value<T>(key) } -> std::same_as<T>;
    { t.template get_value<T>(index, keys...) } -> std::same_as<T>;

    { t.set_cache(keys...) } -> std::same_as<void>;
    { t.get_list_size() } -> std::same_as<int>;
    { t.init_cache() } -> std::same_as<void>;
    { t.load(json_body) } -> std::same_as<void>;
    { t.contains(key) } -> std::same_as<bool>;

    { t.set_root_value(value) } -> std::same_as<void>;
    { t.release() } -> std::same_as<JSON_VALUE>;


};


class JsonUtil {
public:

    template<json_concept JSON_OPERATOR>
    JsonUtil(std::string body, JSON_OPERATOR& json_impl) {
        json_impl.load(body);
    }
    
       template<typename T, json_concept JSON_OPERATOR, typename KEY>
    T get_value(JSON_OPERATOR& json_impl, KEY&&  key) {
        return json_impl.template get_value<T>(std::forward<KEY>(key));
    }


    template<typename T, json_concept JSON_OPERATOR, typename... KEYS>
    T get_value(JSON_OPERATOR& json_impl, KEYS&& ... keys) {
        return json_impl.template get_value<T>(std::forward<KEYS>(keys)...);
    }

    template<json_concept JSON_OPERATOR, typename... KEYS>
    void set_cache(JSON_OPERATOR& json_impl, KEYS&& ... keys) {
        json_impl.set_cache(std::forward<KEYS>(keys)...);
    }

    template<json_concept JSON_OPERATOR>
    void init_cache(JSON_OPERATOR& json_impl) {
        json_impl.init_cache();
    }
};



class IJson {
public:
  template<typename T, typename KEY>
    T get_value(KEY&& key) {
      
      return T();
      }
  
  void load(std::string body) { };
};

int main()
{
  IJson dd = IJson{};
        JsonUtil jsoncpp(std::string("dummy"), dd);

}
```

This code used to run with clang++-10. When I started using g++-11 it fails to compile with following error:

```
conc.cpp:26:14: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be at least 3)
   26 |     template<json_concept JSON_OPERATOR>
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
conc.cpp:4:9: note: provided for ‘template<class T, class ... KEYS, class KEY, class JSON_VALUE> concept json_concept’
    4 | concept json_concept = requires(T t, int index, std::string& json_body, KEYS... keys, KEY key, JSON_VALUE value)
```

What is the problem and how do I solve it please. Is the solution really to provide all templates types each time I invoke a function part of the concept even though not all template argument would be used?

The g++ version is 11.1.0

Comment: Looks like you're missing `#include <concepts>` (at the very least). Why that wasn't required before is the mystery, here.

Comment: That does not solve the problem though. But yes strange that the compiler recognizes concept without the header file

Comment: In which g++ version did this work? I tried, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3 and 10.4 and all reject it.

Comment: I was not sure about it, so I did a reverse engineer it - and it actually turns out I was building using clang++-10. I updated the text. So if you try that, or even here https://cpp.sh/ you will succeed to compile the code

Comment: All concepts-aware versions of clang accept it. All versions of gcc reject it. Clang is wrong. You are not using concepts with template parameters correctly. See [this passage](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#param-4) in the standard and the example that follows. You also cannot have a template parameter pack that is not the last parameter in this context.

Comment: So how would I write the constructor: 
 Do I need to do something like 

`template<typename T, typename key, typename value, json_concept<T, key, value> JSON_OPERATOR>
    JsonUtil(std::string body, JSON_OPERATOR& json_impl) {
        json_impl.load(body);
    }`

Comment: and why does the compiler say that one template argument was provided but at least 3 is needed. I dont provide any template argument , and we have 4 template argument?

Comment: You need to step back and re-evaluate your design. It is fundamentally broken.

Comment: that does not sound good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using concepts with template parameters correctly. Clang is totally wrong in accepting your code. Its support for concepts doesn't seem to be mature enough.

If you have:

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
concept foo = ...
```

then the correct usage of `foo` is with *two* template type arguments:

```
template <foo<int, char> Z> class bar ...
template <typename X, foo<X,X> Z> class baz...
```

Otherwise the concept has no idea what `B` and `C` are.

See [this passage](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#param-4) in the draft standard.

For this reason you cannot have a template parameter pack in the middle of the concept. Move it to the end:

```
template<typename T, typename KEY, typename JSON_VALUE, typename...KEYS>
concept json_concept = ...
```

Then something like this should work:

```
template<typename K, typename V, typename ... Ks, 
         json_concept<K, V, Ks> JSON_OPERATOR>
JsonUtil(std::string body, JSON_OPERATOR& json_impl) {
    json_impl.load(body);
}
```

But this is just the beginning of the problem.

You write

```
t.template get_value<T>(key)
```

but this makes no sense. `T` is the name of the type that satisfies `json_concept`, in your example `IJson`. So you are passing `IJson` as the template parameter of `IJson::get_value<IJson>`. This is not how `get_value` is supposed to be used. You should be using something like

```
value = t.template get_value<JSON_VALUE>(key);
```

It is unclear what the other two overloads of `get_value` correspond to in `IJson`. `IJson` cannot satisfy `json_concepts` with all the requirements, whatever syntax you use to express them. It simply doesn't have all the required overloads.

It is also unclear how one can have such a parameterized concept where only part of the parameters participate in some requirements. Consider this:

```
template<json_concept JSON_OPERATOR<???>>
JsonUtil(std::string body, JSON_OPERATOR& json_impl) {
    json_impl.load(body);
}
```

The concept requires you to provide key, keys, and value, but none of those is used  in `load` and there is no good way to provide them in this context. You could use some defaults but this is sweeping the dirt under the rug.

Comment: Regarding get_value. I think there is a misundersanding here. get_value is basically a  function that returns something by value with type `T` . It can be int, string, double etc.

Comment: So a get_value function might be:
`template<typename T typename KEY>
T get_value(KEY&& key) {
    return T();
}`

Comment: @A2LBK `get_value` gets two template parameters: the type of the key, and the type of the value. In your concept the type of the key is called `KEY` and the type of the value is called `JSON_VALUE`. `T` is the json container itself.

Comment: That is not the intention. How can you see that `T` is the json container. So,  the pure intention of `get_value` is to have a function that returns the json value in one of the primitive types, such as string, int, double etc. 

The `JSON_VALUE`  is essentially the json container. That is my intention with this.

Comment: @A2LBK Look at the template head of the concept. `template<typename T, typename KEY, typename JSON_VALUE, typename...KEYS>
concept json_concept` See `T` there? It's that `T`. You cannot invent an identifier out of thin air.

Comment: Yes I do see that T and that is the intention. I need to template my type T somehow ? 
Dont I get to choose what T is used for. Here I purely use T for the get_value functions. 

So the use would be e.g. :: `std::string value = JsonImpl.get_value<std::string>("key");`

JSON_VALUE is not involved here. JSON_VALUE is only involved when I would need the underlaying container of the Json datatype

Comment: @A2LBK You are calling `t.get_value`. `t` has type `T`. So `T` is the container type. If you want `JSON_VALUE` to be the container, you need to call `j.get_value` where `j` has type `JSON_VALUE`. It will also help if you move `JSON_VALUE` to the first position in the list. I recommend ditching `T`. Use descriptive names: KEY, VALUE and CONTAINER.

Comment: ahhhh . I completely missed that sorry.  Now that I have realized what you mean. Do I actually need anything before `get_value` (and the rest of the functions . Could  they not just bee "free" within the concept. 


It is amazing how Clang did work completely fine including writing test functions to test each functionality

Comment: @A2LBK The problem is that `get_value` is a template itself. C++ concepts *cannot* express requirements of the form "type X has a method Y which is a template callable with any argument type". They only can express "type X has a method Y callable with argument Z" where Z is some specific type. Z can depend on concept parameters, but it cannot just appear out of thin air in the requirement. So no, it cannot be free. `load` can be free as it is not a template.

Comment: Many thanks. very insightful!

Comment: One more question popped up while working on this. If I got a function that takes a concept `foo ( json_concept<jsonContainer, std::string> auto&& functor); `

Here I actually need to specify some value at the template level so I specify something, e.g. a string. However, I can still invoke  `functor.get_value<double>("blabla");`  within `foo` which too me seems a bit odd

Comment: The concept says you can call `get_value<std::string>`. It doesn't say you *cannot* call `get_value<double>`, and if you do that, this is not checked until instantiation. That's the "lite" part of the "concepts lite". They don't do everything we want.

Comment: Well in reality it is fine that it only gets checked once invoked. The only reason I pass the string in the template argument is for the compiler to pass. '